# How to call HTTP Request from Ionic 3 PWA?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I am developing an Ionic 3 Progressive Web App(PWA). I want to call http get request. How to call this? Since Cordova not supports I can't use native http plugin. Can anybody help me on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Angular 5 HttpClient. You can find examples 
here:
[Consuming REST APIs with Ionic](https://medium.com/@chathurangijks/create-rest-api-with-json-server-and-consume-in-angular-5-httpclient-using-ionic-3-application-66bee52deb6e) 
or here
[Ionic Academy](https://ionicacademy.com/http-calls-ionic/)